# How to auto select the value in Edit form?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Can you help me to correct this code

```
<select name="ClassHall">
    <?php
    while ($Hall = mysql_fetch_array($resultHall, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $Hall['HallName'];?>"

    <?php if($ClassHall == '$Hall['HallName']'){ echo(' selected '); } ?>

     > <?php echo $Hall['HallName'];?> </option>

    <?php
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

I would like to auto select the value in Edit form. 
It have syntax error in '$Hall['HallName']' part.

Answer (score 1):

You have the variable in a singlequotes on this line:

```
 <?php if($ClassHall == '$Hall['HallName']'){ echo(' selected '); } ?>
```

Try changing that to something like:

```
 <?php if($ClassHall == $Hall['HallName']){ echo(' selected '); } ?>
```

Comment: I try and its Ok but I get no value in selection list ):

Comment: Did you double check (with print_r or something) that you're getting values from the database? Maybe that's the problem.